# How would you fix an inflection point on engineered hardwood?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, engineered-flooring

Looks like I didn't have a perfectly level subfloor and now, there's a slight inflection (peak) in the finished installation of the 1/2" inch engineered maple hardwood floor.

Other detail, my girlfriend thinks I'm insane with this. She's probably right.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks more like a manufacturing or installation defect to me.

Comment: Is there really something solid underneath there or does it flex if you stand  on it?

Comment: @brhans it's solid

Comment: It looks like what happens when the ends are driven together too tight. This one is the worst, others suggest being driven a bit too tight as well

Comment: Yeah, it was my first self install :-( Thought I was doing the right thing. I'm guessing there's there's no easy fix...

Comment: Throw a rug on it and move along. I know you can see it now, but in time, you'll learn to ignore it.

Comment: Wait until winter and/or drier weather. It'll disappear. Until next Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt, your install looks good. Replace the board, should take a whole 20 mins takes us 5-7 mins. You might realize something small was under the wood. Worse case, you replace both and issue is gone. Remember to rip the bottom of the groove.

Comment: Tangentially-related: how on earth do you replace a tongue-in-groove board in 20 minutes? Is there a secret handshake?